# How to create matrix in R while inputting evaluated data?

Tags: r, matrix

I have to create a matrix with the values that I had recieved so far from my evaluation.
For instance, so far I have the value of e1 = 2 and e2 =3 
How can I put these e1 and e2 in 2x1 matrix ?

Comment: Please make sure to do a basic search before asking a question, there is plenty of clear documentation on this online and here on stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

Use the `matrix` function and specify the number of columns for this.

```
e1 <- 2 
e2 <- 3

m <- matrix(c(e1, e2), ncol = 1)

m
#      [,1]
# [1,]    2
# [2,]    3
```